# How to use the sentence embedding in the android app using tf-lite?

Tags: java, android, c++, tensorflow, tflite

I am following the [official](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/text_embedder) guide in order to include a sentence embedding model into an android application. For the model weights it points towards the [tf-hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/universal-sentence-encoder-qa-ondevice/1) link with weights provided from google.

Code there seems to be provided for C++ use-case. Is there anyway I can use the Java API to do the inference?
I tried using the code below following Java-API resources I could find.

```
MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel
                = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(context, MODEL_PATH);
InterpreterApi tflite = new InterpreterFactory().create(
                tfliteModel, new InterpreterApi.Options());
```

But it gives the following error: `Encountered unresolved custom op: TFSentencepieceTokenizeOp` while loading the model

---

**With C++ NDK**

The model in the TF-hub also points to the [TFlite-support](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support) library and in particular to the [header](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/blob/master/tensorflow_lite_support/cc/task/text/universal_sentence_encoder_qa.h) file in c++ format.

I did the following steps:

1. Create a `cpp` folder in the `app.main` location and added NDK stuff required for it to work using CMake.
2. Following the [add native code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#create-sources) guide. I added the above mentioned header file to the `app.main` location
3. I added the `native-lib.cpp` following tutorials etc and can now call a dummy c++ function from my Java code using JNI.
4. **Do I need to add the entire tf-lite repository for c++ in order to make the inference work? What's the efficient and clean way of doing that?**

what my `native-lib` looks like

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_dummy_Caller_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Any help is appreciated.